# Python TelegramBot Вывод информации из базы данных Mysql через кнопки

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, telebot

я работаю в Python 3 и базы данных Mysql 10.1.13-MariaDB

Хочу из базы данных вывести информацию(select) используя кнопки TelegramBot. Например если в телеграм боте нажать на кнопку "Остатки" или "Долг" используя запрос отправить результат пользователю. У меня есть код кнопки и запрос НО у меня не получается объединить их если нажать первую кнопку ответить первым запросам или если нажать на вторую кнопку ответить вторим запросам (не хватает знаний) Извините, если тупой вопрос, я новичок. Подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import mysql.connector

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

db = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="hosil"
)

kontragent = db.cursor()
kontragent.execute("SELECT * FROM kontragent")
myresult = kontragent.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
    print(x)

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM product")
myresult1 = cursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult1:
    print(x)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=2)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Склад")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Долг")
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)

    send_mess = f"<b>Привет {message.from_user.first_name}!</b>\nВведите "
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_mess, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Немного не понял вопрос, предположу что тебе не понятно, как выводить при нажатии разных кнопок - разные данные. Если не прав - ответь в комментарии под моим сообщением)

Судя по примеру [отсюда](https://habr.com/ru/post/448310/), клавиатура позволяет отправлять сообщение одним нажатием. Соответственно необходимо просто прикрутить ловлю этого сообщения, например:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'долг':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, <переменная с данными>)
```

Comment: у меня две кнопки и два запроса хочу чтобы при нажатии первого кнопки сработал запрос а при нажатии второго кнопки сработал другой запрос

Comment: чем твой код может мне помочь объясни?

Comment: А вот насчет того, чем мой код может тебе помочь, ответ прост - вместо bot.send_message вставь код своего запроса)

Comment: что не понятного в моём вопросе? ты напиши я исправлю! (есть две кнопки две запроса надо при нажатии кнопок ответить прилепленным к ним запросом из базы)

Comment: @ariana я же уже объяснил в прошлом комментарии как сделать) Замени код отправки сообщения с переменной <переменная с данными>, кодом запроса или тем, что тебе нужно сделать при нажатии кнопки.